# jQuery - go to page, take screenshot without load this page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I am trying to write an application in style of 4chan thread saver. I know that I can make a screenshot using html2canvas and even managed to do it. But how to load a html page without load it in browser? I care about keep the style of the page

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot do that without loading the page using Canvas. For that you will need server side code.

Comment: There are scriptable headless browsers; phantomJS is one you could try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a jQuery issue. However, you should be able to do a XMLHttpRequest  [defined here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and supply the url, to get the web page html back.